# Consecutive whitespace reduction

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, strings, parsing

I pursued an according algorithm with an absolute best performance, the following class embodies the solution.

Any comment is welcome.

```cs
class TextCompressor
{
    private const char Seperator = '\x20';

    private StringBuilder builder;

    public TextCompressor()
    {
        this.builder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public string Compress(string str)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        int end = str.Length - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(str[i]))
            {
                if (i != offset)
                {
                    if (str[i] == Seperator)
                    {
                        if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(str[i + 1]))
                        {
                            i++;

                            continue;
                        }

                        builder.Append(str, offset, (i - offset) + 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        builder.Append(str, offset, i - offset);
                        builder.Append(Seperator);
                    }
                }

                offset = i + 1;
            }
        }

        if (offset != 0)
        {
            builder.Append(str, offset, str.Length - offset);

            return Char.IsWhiteSpace(str[end]) ? Release().TrimEnd() : Release();
        }

        return Trim(str);
    }

    private static string Trim(string s)
    {
        return (s.Length != 0 && (Char.IsWhiteSpace(s[0]) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(s[s.Length - 1]))) ? s.Trim() : s;
    }

    private string Release()
    {
        string s = builder.ToString();

        builder.Length = 0;

        return s;
    }
}
```

## `Compress` vs. `Regex.Replace`

.. using `\s{2,}`

String: `"   The   quick    brown     fox      jumps       over        the         lazy          dog.   "`

- 1.97017 * (10 times faster)
- 19.333874

String: `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."`

- 0.485821 * (16 times faster)
- 8.049062

Comment: You might want to take a look at [some tips for posting a good question.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562). I believe the *main* problem here is not just that there is a lack of a "How can I improve this?"-question, but the lack of description about what your code does. Also, while there has been discussion in the past about [how to deal with questions not asking a question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/790/should-a-post-with-no-specific-questions-imply-a-general-review), I recommend adding a note like "Any and all comments welcome".

Comment: The purpose of the code, and therefore the point of the question, seems obvious enough from the title alone. I see no reason to downvote or close this question.

Comment: Spelling: **`Separator`**

Answer (score 7):

## The good stuff

Your code looks neat and is pretty fast.

## Remarks

I would second that the name `Separator` isn't chosen well and would like to suggest `SpaceChar` which is more obvious.

## Review

The biggest problem I see is the missing `null` check for the parameter of the `public` method `Compress`. Throwing an `ArgumentNullException` instead of getting a `NullReferenceException` is better.

The `Trim(string s)` method doesn't buy you much. Saving some `Ticks` this way is a optimization which comes with less readable code. Just a call to `string.Trim()` is sufficient.

Initializing the `StringBuilder` like [@Shelby115](/users/50770) suggested in his [answer](/a/118668) won't save you a lot but it is a good habit to do so. If you know how big the buffer of the `StringBuilder` can increase you should use that knowledge. With the default constructor the `StringBuilder`'s internal buffer has a size of `16` which is doubled each time it is reached.

Instead of having this method in the `TextCompressor` class which implies that it compresses some text I would suggest making this an extension method.

I would like to suggest using a `char []` instead of a `StringBuilder` and change the arrow code to something like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ReplaceMultipleWhiteSpaceWithSpace(this string str)
    {
        return str.ReplaceMultipleWhiteSpaceWithSeparator('\x20');
    }

    public static string ReplaceMultipleWhiteSpaceWithSeparator(this string str, char separator)
    {
        if (str == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(str); }
        if (str.Length == 0) { return str; }

        int end = str.Length;
        int destinationOffset = 0;
        bool foundWhiteSpace = true;
        char current = separator;
        char[] destination = new char[end];

        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(str[i]))
            {
                if (foundWhiteSpace) { continue; }

                foundWhiteSpace = true;
                current = separator;
            }
            else
            {
                foundWhiteSpace = false;
                current = str[i];
            }
            destination[destinationOffset] = current;
            destinationOffset++;
        }


        int newSize = foundWhiteSpace
            ? IndexOfLastNonWhithSpaceChar(destination, destinationOffset)
            : destinationOffset;

        Array.Resize(ref destination, newSize);

        return new string(destination);

    }
    private static int IndexOfLastNonWhithSpaceChar(char[] values, int startIndex)
    {
        if (startIndex >= values.Length) { startIndex = values.Length - 1; }
        for (int i = startIndex; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(values[i]) && values[i]!='\0')
            {
                return i +1;
            }
        }
        return startIndex;
    }
}
```

## Some numbers

You mentioned in your question that you have measured the performance and provided some numbers, which are unfortunately missing a unit. I couldn't compare them to my numbers so I just measured your method and my method.

For both scenarios each benchmarked method first does a warm-up phase for 5000 ms and then it is called **10000** times and returns the average of `StopWatch.ElapsedTicks` which is then converted to milliseconds.

1. Passed in a string with `Length` of **7368** containing **4124** white space characters.

   Yours: **0,02897**23431498079 **ms**
   Mine: **0,03082**40396927017 **ms**
   Other: **0,11075**9507042254 **ms**
2. Passed in a string with `Length` of **1591488** containing **890784** white space characters.

   Yours: **6,70626**021126761 **ms**
   Mine: **7,66718**351472471 **ms**
   Other: **42,39482**42637644 **ms**

So, what is **Other**? It is only taking **42 ms** for the second scenario which is IMO fast enough for such a task. It's very simple:

```
string.Join(" ", str.Split().Where(s => s.Length > 0));
```

Comment: Your method has some notable properties: **(1)** It is 0.3 times faster for small words of ≈12 characters. **(2)** It is 0.6 times slower for words without consecutive whitespace.

Comment: That means: Your method is faster in cases where strings are purposely populated with consecutive whitespace, though there are very few real scenarios were such is necessary.

Comment: I insist that `Seperator` was among the best options because the name doesn't attempt to substitute its value, rather it offers a contextually-correct indication. Labels should not carry more significance than their context, that is bad design.

Comment: I forgot - `IndexOfLastNonWhithSpaceChar` throws exceptions upon certain cases of trailing whitespace.

Comment: Fixed the `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: _Your code looks neat_ this is a joke, isn't it? - with the `if { if { if { if` ception? never ;-P

Answer (score 5):

You present uncommented code: don't expect many to be willing to read it carefully.

Reading `absolute best performance`, I expected open coded array handling. (I would have been pleased with a model of performance, including assumptions about inputs.)

In `Compress(string)`, there is a for loop - with the loop control variable modified four nesting levels down.

With no tangible specification, to use of both `TextCompressor.Seperator` and `Char.IsWhiteSpace()` is confusing.

Comment: The loop should rarely enter beyond the first condition. Could you elaborate on 'open coded array handling', does that imply unsafe code? I wouldn't mind leaving that out.

Comment: I expected filling a `char[]` with characters wanted and constructing a string from it (`new string(chars, offset, length)`), maybe even a `str.ToCharArray()` to use array indexing instead of "string indexing".

Comment: Constructing a new string is only necessary upon consecutive whitespace characters, this algorithm behaves accordingly. Iterating `char[]` is faster than `string`, but the initial requirement to copy the string disables the benefit.

Comment: The first paragraph of the answer should be moved to a comment

Comment: The `Compress` method has no notable assumptions, it doesn't even compulsively optimize the `StringBuilder` according to the string's length. However, there is one premise: Every encountered sequence of whitespace character must ultimately deem equal to `Seperator`. Besides, it performs a `Trim` operation, even if trailing whitespace does not exceed a single instance.

Comment: @Avenicci: without assumptions about input, how _do_ you assess performance?

Comment: @greybeard - I compare it to `Regex.Replace` using `\s{2,}`

Comment: @Avenicci : I'd consider the information in your last comment a valuable addition to the question: `absolute best performance` without context looks cocky. (Not _quite_ sure why I assume neither you nor me to be a native speaker of English - I find it neither easy to hit the right tone, nor to correctly recognise deviations from "plain".)

Comment: @greybeard - It appears cocky because 'performance' is amplified by two adjectives instead of one, which are more awkwardly interpreted as nouns. I added a benchmark result.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to greybeard's answer here are some tips to improve the design of your code.

- **Naming**: Perhaps you should rename your class to specify that it compresses white-space and not all text. It may sound silly but these details can be important when you're pressed for time or are revisiting code 2 weeks to 2 years after you originally wrote it (This same philosophy applies the same to commenting your classes/functions).
- **StringBuilder**: Perhaps you should delay the construction of the `StringBuilder` instance until you call `Compress` this way you can pass the constructor the length of the string potentially improving performance depending on how long the string is. (`StringBuilder` starts at a default capacity and simply doubles the capacity each time it is reached. By providing the capacity ahead of time you can prevent this from having to happen. The longer the string the more it will happen).
- **Boolean Variables**: I find it extremely helpful to almost always place my boolean conditions into well-named variables. This way I can tell quickly at first glance what the condition is doing without having to read too much into it's specific implementation.

  ```
  var isSeparator = str[i] == Seperator;
  if (isSeparator)
  {
      ...
  }
  ```

For this scenario it's not really necessary but I think it gets my point across.

- **Casing**: You seem a bit inconsistent with your casing at the class-level scope. Since you have `Seperator` capitalized I would suggest `builder` should also be for consistency. Classes and class-members pascal-cased and local variables should be camel-cased. This way you automatically know if something is restricted to the local-scope or if it's at a higher-scope.

Comment: **Naming** - The name `TextCompressor` is highly ambiguous, though it was the most sensical name I encountered.

Comment: **StringBuilder** - This benefit only applies for the first string, after that, `Compress` remains cluttered with a null check. It is better to use `StringBuilder.EnsureCapacity`, although the benefit is futile in practice.

Comment: **Casing** - Note that `Seperator` is a constant field, unlike `builder`. For constants, pascal case is the most conventional.

Comment: @Avenicci Ah, I was mistaken on your usage of `Compress` for the `StringBuilder` suggestion. Perhaps this points out how helpful comments can be.

Comment: @Avenicci As for the Casing suggestion, I personally stand by making members Pascal. I looked it up and apparently Microsoft suggests camel-casing for Fields. The way I see it is a choice between more easily noticing the difference between a Property vs Field or more easily noticing Scope differences. In my experiences, the latter is more important to me.

Comment: @Avenicci For the naming, I would suggest a simple `WhiteSpaceCompressor`. I capitalized the 'S' to match Microsoft casing in the `System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` function.

Comment: Camel case for fields avoids ambiguity with class names and properties, that may be the most realistic reason to use it. Besides, it hints to the significance of the addressed identifier.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Separator` constant - this:

> ```
> private const char Separator = '\x20';
> ```

Is really just an obfuscated way of doing this:

```
private const char WhiteSpace = ' ';
```

And since the only usage of this `Separator` is here:

> ```
> if (str[i] == Seperator)
> ```

You could very well replace it with this:

```
if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(str[i]))
```

And do away with it completely, and have clearer code.

---

You're using `this` to qualify `builder`. Fine. But please, be consistent about it; the `Compress` method isn't qualifying it, and `builder` looks just like any other local variable, but it's a field.

Either you qualify fields with `this`, or you don't.

And if you don't, then name your fields so that it's impossible to mistake them for a local:

```
private readonly StringBuilder _builder;

public TextCompressor()
{
    _builder = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Because the `_builder`/`builder` reference isn't reassigned anywhere, it's not clear whether that's the intent. Making the field `readonly` removes all ambiguity and tells everyone reading the code that this reference lives and dies with the class instance.

You could also initialize it inline, and get rid of the default/parameterless constructor altogether:

```
private readonly StringBuilder _builder = new StringBuilder();
```

Comment: You should *never* assign concrete names to constants. Would you approve a declaration like `const A = 'A'`? I know, whitespace is a category instead of a unit, but what if you need another whitespace-involving constant in the future? In that case, you could narrow `Whitespace` to `Space`, but there lies the mentioned pitfall.

Comment: **Why do you need that constant at all?** - To ensure that the output has consistent breaks (spaces or linebreaks).

Comment: **this.builder** - In overall, I use `this` consistently, but the embedded code does not contain evidence. I only use `this` in constructors to ensure that all `set` operations are well-aligned. It is not uncommon for parameters and fields to share names.

Comment: Consistently wrong then. The reason for using `this` as a qualifier is to improve readability by disambiguating fields from locals and parameters. That said you don't need the constant, as I demonstrated.

Comment: Do you think that alignment does not enhance readability? I cannot argue with that. And yes, if consistent line breaks are desirable, than an extra field is necessary, be it constant or static.

Comment: The constant represents a single whitespace character, it is not needed, read my answer again. If it's used elsewhere than in the code you posted, note that only the code you posted is up for review.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug:

```
    int end = str.Length - 1;
```

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
>     {
>         if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(str[i]))
>         {
>             if (i != offset)
>             {
>                 if (str[i] == Seperator)
>                 {
>                     if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(str[i + 1]))
> ```

That `str[i+1]` can be out of range, on the last iteration of the loop.